# Cannot delete a record with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to delete a record from pymongo and I cannot understand the reason that the record is still in my connection.

Here is my code:

```
_id = bottle.request.forms.get('_id')
collection.remove({'_id':_id})
```

the _id variable is an input text from an HTML form in my website. Here is the output of the remove method.

```
{u'connectionId': 86, u'ok': 1.0, u'err': None, u'n': 0}
```

I cannot see any error, but the record is still in my collection. Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert `_id` variable (that's of type `str`) to `ObjectId` type first

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
if type(_id) is not ObjectId:
    _id = ObjectId(_id)
```

Take a look: http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.7rc0/tutorial.html#querying-by-objectid

Comment: I have already tried it and I have the same message and the record still there.

Comment: You are either using the wrong collection or _id is empty or malformed

Comment: For a reason, when I request the _id from the form, I got one more pair of quotes in the string. Thank you :)